# SQL Filtering group data

Tags: mysql, filtering

i've got a DB like this

```
id name group
```

with data like this

```
1 john A
2 john B
3 charles B
4 peter B
5 rose B
6 charles A
7 justin C
```

As you can see, the posibilities  are that one ID it's associated with one group, or more than one group

i need a query for filtering

a) are in group A and B
b) are in group A but not B
c) are only in group A

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
    a. select distinct name from tablename where group = 'A' or group = 'B';
    b. select distinct name from tablename where group = 'A' and group <> 'B';
    c. select distinct name from tablename where group = 'A' and 
         group not in (select distinct(t1.group) from tablename t1 
                         where t1.group <> 'A');
```

Comment: This looks fine, the only problem it's when i can't count groups, on (c) the not in should be able to make it without listing manually them

Comment: @Zuker ok, I have made it more dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I like approaching these problems using `group by` and the `having` clause.  For your first question:

```
select name
from table
group by name
having sum(group = 'A') > 1 and sum(group = 'B') > 0;
```

The other two are:

```
having sum(group = 'A') > 1 and sum(group = 'B') = 0;
having sum(group = 'A') > 1 and sum(group <> 'A') = 0;
```